# PHP/MySQL Update code

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to call a row update from php to an mysql database. It fails out but when i try to call an insert new row formated just the same it works.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO auth (username, password, studycode, description, server) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$studycode', '$description', '$server')");
```

but this code fails

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE auth SET username='$username', password='$password', studycode='$studycode', description='$description', server='$server' WHERE index='$id' LIMIT 1;");
```

index is the first column and its the key/id for the table.

Edit:
Ok so i just went into mysql admin and tried the exact command my code would have sent to track the error.

```
UPDATE auth SET username='username', password='password', studycode='ab9102y', description='test change', server='server2' WHERE index='5' LIMIT 1;
```

gives me the error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index='5' LIMIT 1' at line 1
```

Comment: "Fails out" with what error?  Are you sure there's a record with the ID you're passing in?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Change the code to this:
    $result = mysql_query(...) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibly a reserved keyword issue with index.  Try:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE auth SET username='$username', password='$password', studycode='$studycode', description='$description', server='$server' WHERE `index` ='$id'");
```

Comment: You should really sanitize your input here to prevent injection, either with prepared statements or escaping the values.

Comment: It's easiest if you always put \`s around all the fields as standard practice to be honest. There's a ton of reserved words and some are really good field names (`desc` is quite common).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because the word `index` is a reserved word in MySQL. There for you need change your where clause to:

```
WHERE `index` = '$id'
```

Notice the ticks around index.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid these kind of problems I usually name my tables like this: (for ex. a users table)

```
> CREATE TABLE usr_user (
>          usr_id INT,
>          usr_name VARCHAR(100),
>          usr_email VARCHAR(100) );
```

On a side note:
Learn about prepared statements; I would be very scared of using the SQL code you have there.

Answer (score -1):

You have "UPDATE atuh" instead of "UPDATE auth". Spelling error on here or in your code?

EDIT: Try removing the quotes around your index = '$id' and also you want to remove the semi-colon from your queries in [PHP](http://us.php.net/function.mysql-query).

Comment: just that part that I copied.

Answer (score -2):

try this out

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE auth SET username='$username', password='$password', studycode='$studycode', description='$description', server='$server' WHERE index='$id'");